# Elegant way for passing different number of arguments in a conditional statement

Tags: python

I want to call the group_by function on a query by different number of similar arguments based on a condition like so:

```
if hour:
    q = q.group_by(extract('year', Action.action_date_time),
                   extract('month', Action.action_date_time),
                   extract('day', Action.action_date_time),
                   extract('hour', Action.action_date_time))
elif day:
    q = q.group_by(extract('year', Action.action_date_time),
                   extract('month', Action.action_date_time),
                   extract('day', Action.action_date_time))
```

ans so on.

How can I make this code more pythonic?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use a list comprehension:

```
by_hour = ['year', 'month', 'day', 'hour']
by_day = ['year', 'month', 'day']

if hour:
    q = q.group_by(*[extract(x, Actin.action_date_time) for x in by_hour])
elif day:
    q = q.group_by(*[extract(x, Actin.action_date_time) for x in by_day])
```

You could also have a dictionary to store the different possibilities:

```
by_ = {
  'hour': ['year', 'month', ...],
  'day': ['year', ...],
}
```

And with this specific ordered data you could also use one list and slice it:

```
time = ['year', 'month', 'day', 'hour']
if hour:
    q = q.group_by(*[extract(x, Action.action_date_time) for x in time])
elif day:
    q = q.group_by(*[extract(x, Action.action_date_time) for x in time[:2]])
elif month:
    q = q.group_by(*[extract(x, Action.action_date_time) for x in time[:1]])
```

Answer (score 1):

```
by_hour = ( extract('year',  Action.action_date_time),
            extract('month', Action.action_date_time),
            extract('day',   Action.action_date_time),
            extract('hour',  Action.action_date_time) )

by_day = ( extract('year',  Action.action_date_time),
           extract('month', Action.action_date_time),
           extract('day',   Action.action_date_time) )

grouping = by_hour

q = q.group_by( *grouping )
```

Comment: Thank you. Is there any way to get rid of the repetition?

Comment: @betrunken yes, you could define by_day first and then by_hour=(*by_day, extract('hour',...), but i would advise against it for better readability.

Answer (score 1):

Based on @grepe answer and your comments, if you want to get rid of the repetition I guess you can try something like this :

```
grouping = [extract('year',  Action.action_date_time),
            extract('month', Action.action_date_time),
            extract('day',   Action.action_date_time)]

if hour:
    grouping.append(extract('hour',  Action.action_date_time))

q = q.group_by( *grouping )
```